# Correctly remove object (with code example) iOS

Tags: ios, application-lifecycle

Does the following code (`removeViews`) correctly remove the reference to the objects, i.e delete them, so I do not keep making more `Views` when the method `createViews` is called. `createViews` creates the views and `removeViews` sets them to nil. ***Note:*** this is a very simple example to enhance understanding, and serves no actual purpose.

```
-(void) createViews{
    UITableView * tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)];
    tableView.delegate=self;
    tableView.datasource = self;
    self.mainTableView = tableView;//self.mainTableView is a weak reference
    [self.view.superView addSubview: self.mainTableView];

    UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,400)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.mainView = view;//self.mainView is a strong reference

    [self.view.superView addSubviews:self.mainView];

}

-(void) removeViews{
    self.mainView = nil;
    self.mainTableView=nil;



 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove them from their superView and then set them to nil

```
-(void) removeViews{
        [self.mainView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.mainTableView removeFromSuperview];
        self.mainView = nil;
        self.mainTableView=nil;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, what about if the views were only added to the view, like so `[self.view addSubview: self.mainView]` or is this the same thing?

Comment: The above code will remove self.mainView from its superView